# PluginException: No plugin registered for (.nt, <class 'rdflib.serializer.Serializer'>)

Tags: python, rdflib, knowledge-graph, n-triples

I am able to serialize in `.ttl` format but when I tried serialize the rdf graph in `(.nt,.ntriples,.nt11 format)` by python. Everytime it is showing error:
`PluginException: No plugin registered for (.nt, <class 'rdflib.serializer.Serializer'>)`

using `g.serialize(format='.nt')`

Anybody can help?Thanks!

Comment: you should read again the documentation and check what `format` expects as keywords: https://rdflib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro_to_parsing.html - hint: it is not a file extension with a leading dot. also pydoc can help in future: https://rdflib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/apidocs/rdflib.html#rdflib.Graph.serialize

Comment: Thanks, it works without the leading dot.